# @PreAuthorize returns 403

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt, authorization

I have a following method in the controller

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public String hello() {
    return "Hello " + JWTRequestFilter.UserClaim;
}
```

When a user who has the `ADMIN` role tries to access the `/hello`, 403 is returned. I have enabled the following in the websecurity class.

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

Below is the JWT token.

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzZW50aHVyYW4iLCJSb2xlcyI6WyJBRE1JTiIsIlVTRVIiXSwiZXhwIjoxNTkzMDE0NDE5LCJpYXQiOjE1OTI5Nzg0MTl9.-7lTav3Nux8WVafUBGXjOxtXcE-r0fpfjb7wM7hrg6w
```

Even the JWT token has the role but still i'm getting 403. Does this preauthorize annotation see the role from the JWT or does it make a DB call and check the role of a user.Even I have used the `@PreAuthrize` annotation but still getting the same behaviour. How to resolve this 403. Below I have attached the `JWTRequestFilter` class.

```
public class JWTRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailService userDetailService;

    @Autowired
    private JWTUtil jwtUtil;

    public static String UserClaim = "";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if(authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username =  jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
            UserClaim = username;
        }

        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails= this.userDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }

        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

This is how I'm generating the JWT token and how I set the roles.

```
public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> Userroles = new HashSet<>();
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    for(Role role:user.getRoles()){
        Userroles.add(role.getName());
    }
    claims.put("Roles",Userroles.toArray());
    return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
}
```

Comment: Are you setting your Roles JWT to Claims of your security Context ?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I have attached the JWTRequestFilter class

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati I need to know does the preAuthorize check the JWT or does it check from the DB whether the user has the perticular role.

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati I have attached the code for of how i'm generating the token.

Comment: try it with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") like in this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggested Approach to identify the issue**

```
        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails= this.userDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                String authorities = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.joining());
                System.out.println("Authorities granted : " + authorities);
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Valid Token);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("No Token);
        }
```

**Outcome: Token was valid but authorities were not loaded**

```
Authorities granted :
```

**Suggested Solution**
Fix the `MyUserDetailService` to load `Authorities` in `userDetails`

Comment: I have replaced the code still i'm getting 403. I've applied your code and in the log I saw the following Authorities granted :  and there is no value. May be i'm thinking there is no value for the authorities granted that's why it is failing. Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Yes thanks for your advice. I have added a new method inside the MyUserDetailService     private Set getAuthority(User user) {
        Set authorities = new HashSet();
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()));
        });
        return authorities;
    }.    and able to get that work done. Thanks @Kavithakaran for your help on this.

Comment: Also I have updated         return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(), getAuthority(user));

Answer (score 1):

Spring adds the prefix *ROLE_* to the authorities.
You can either implement a setter that appends the role prefix.
Or another much simple way to do it would be to have a separate classe that implements  *GrantedAuthority* interface

```java
public class UserRole implements GrantedAuthority {
    private MyRole role;
    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return "ROLE_" + role.toString();
    }
}
//MyRole is the enum with the different roles ADMIN,VIEWER,...
```